# Navigate to a page in a sub folder on item click in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, portfolio

I'm very new to React JS but watched a few video tutorials on how to build my own portfolio. I want to map my portfolio items which contain an image, title, description, role and link. I managed to map everything except for the link to the detailed page of the respective portfolio item.

Could anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to solve it please?

This is my folder structure:

`src => pages` where the main pages retain and `src => pages => case-studies` where the detailed pages of my portfolio items retain.

[image]

Here's what I got to so far:

**Work.jsx** in the src => pages folder

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import "./Work.css";
import WorkCard from "./WorkCard";
import WorkData from "./WorkData";

const Work = () => {
  return (
    <div className="work">
      <section className="work-section">
        <div className="card">
          <h1 className="underline">My portfolio</h1>
          <p>Here are the case studies of my projects...</p>

          <div className="grid-layout grid-2">
            {
              WorkData.map((val, index) => {
                return (
                  <WorkCard
                    key={index}
                    url={val.url}
                    image={val.image}
                    name={val.name}
                    description={val.description}
                    role={val.role} />
                 );
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Work;
```

**WorkCard.jsx** in the src => pages folder

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const WorkCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <NavLink to={props.url} className="tile-card">
      <img src={props.image} alt={props.name} />
      <div className="details">
        <h2>{props.name}</h2>
        <p className="description" title={props.description}>{props.description}</p>
        <h4 className="role" title={props.role}>Role: {props.role}</h4>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
  );
}

export default WorkCard;
```

**WorkData.jsx** in the src => pages folder

```
import EcoPizza from "../assets/project-icons/ecoPizza.webp";
import Squared from "../assets/project-icons/Squared.webp";
import { EcoPizzaCaseStudy, SquaredCaseStudy } from "./case-studies";

const WorkData = [
  {
    "image": EcoPizza,
    "name": "The UX portfolio item name",
    "description": "This is description part",
    "role": "My role in that project",
    "url": EcoPizzaCaseStudy
  },
  {
    "image": Squared,
    "name": "The UX portfolio item name",
    "description": "This is description part",
    "role": "My role in that project",
    "url": SquaredCaseStudy
  }
];

export default WorkData;
```

**index.js** in the src => pages => case-studies folder

```
export { default as EcoPizzaCaseStudy } from "./eco-pizza/EcoPizzaCaseStudy";
export { default as SquaredCaseStudy } from "./squared/SquaredCaseStudy";
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navigation } from "./components/Navigation";
import { Home, About, Work, Contact, PageNotFound, UnderConstruction } from "./pages";
import { Footer } from "./components/Footer";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <main>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/work" element={<Work />} />
            <Route path="/under-construction" element={<UnderConstruction />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound />}/>
          </Routes>
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the issue you face? What is the question really? If you are wanting to render different "pages" and link to them then you'll need to render a router and routes for each page, and *then* you can link to them. Are you rendering a router and routes? See [mcve].

Comment: Hi @DrewReese So the problem is when I click on the `WorkCard` it doesn't navigate to the detailed page of the relevant item, even though I have provided the URL in the `WorkData.jsx` file. In short I want to be able to click on a portfolio item which will then navigate the user to the UX case study of that portfolio item clicked.

Comment: Right, so can you share your router and routes configuration so we can see what the code is trying to link to?

Comment: Hi again @DrewReese I updated the question with the `App.js` file where my routes are defined. Is it that I need to add my portfolio item routes there too? As I mentioned since this is my very first time at using React JS, I thought setting the route would mean providing the path to the relevant page only like I have done in the `WorkData.jsx` file..

Comment: So is the issue that you click the link and then navigate to `"/work/EcoPizzaCaseStudy"` and then the `PageNotFound` component is rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese It was doing that exact thing at first, but now as of my setup right now it doesn't go anywhere nor throw errors, when I hover over the item the route it shows is `/work` page, when actually I want the view to navigate to the details page of that portfolio item. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing whole concept of routing. You can't just use item as a link to it. For that, we use Routes and then use url by Route defined accordingly.

So you need to fill up your Routes with missing items in App.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navigation } from "./components/Navigation";
import { Home, About, Work, Contact, PageNotFound, UnderConstruction } from "./pages";
import { Footer } from "./components/Footer";
//import required components
import { EcoPizzaCaseStudy, SquaredCaseStudy } from "./case-studies";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <main>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/work" element={<Work />} />
            <Route path="/under-construction" element={<UnderConstruction />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            // Add your routes
            <Route path="/eco-pizza-case-study" element={<EcoPizzaCaseStudy/>} />
            <Route path="/squared-case-study" element={<SquaredCaseStudy/>} />
            <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound />}/>
          </Routes>
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And then for url use that defined path.

Instead `"url": SquaredCaseStudy` just do `"url": "/squared-case-study"`

Any path you choose will work as long as it is **unique**. You can make it `/study/squared` or any other, but you need to define it in App.js to use it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know [React Router](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting) concept first to check how to navigate routes between components. React use React Router Dom to navigate pages. So First you need to create all routes in your projects (name it App.jsx or you can make your own custom Route.jsx file and import to App.jsx)

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Work = lazy(() => import('./pages/Work'));
const EcoPizzaCaseStudy = lazy(() => import('./case-studies/eco-pizza/EcoPizzaCaseStudy'));
const SquaredCaseStudy = lazy(() => import('./case-studies/squared/SquaredCaseStudy'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/work" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/coPizzaCaseStudy/" element={<EcoPizzaCaseStudy />} />
        <Route path="/squaredCaseStudy/" element={<SquaredCaseStudy />} />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

With this way, you can pass urls `coPizzaCaseStudy` and `squaredCaseStudy` to your workData instead of passing components itself. You need to not import components in WorkData.jsx file, just use above texts in url property.

And also In my personal thinking regarding your project structuring, You can make sub folders inside of pages folder for every pages relevant files (For example, make Work folder and put your files `Work.css` ~ `WorkData.jsx`), and instead of having Work.jsx, you can just have index.jsx and copy all code from Work.jsx. This way help you webpack compile engine find right index for your pages (in this case, work page) more easily.
I shared my project folder structure followed best practices. Sub folders under views are every pages. Every folders has index.tsx file for main component, and component sub folders, hooks, and types, etc

[image: Project structure]

And also you need to name `WorkData.jsx` if you are going to expert just object data instead of JSX component. Just name it `WorkData.js` etc.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response to the question. I tried it but it still rendered the "404" page for me. But you are right, I need to structure the folder a lot. Thanks for that tip. :)

Comment: You are doing set route urls correctly in workData.js? It should be same with the url that used in App.jsx routes definition.

Comment: Ahhh... I see. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm correct in understanding your issue, it is that you click the link and then navigate to `"/work/EcoPizzaCaseStudy"`, for example, and then the `PageNotFound` component is rendered, or there is some error.

The code is currently attempting to use an imported React component ***as*** the link target.

```
import EcoPizza from "../assets/project-icons/ecoPizza.webp";
import Squared from "../assets/project-icons/Squared.webp";
import { EcoPizzaCaseStudy, SquaredCaseStudy } from "./case-studies";

const WorkData = [
  {
    "image": EcoPizza,
    "name": "The UX portfolio item name",
    "description": "This is description part",
    "role": "My role in that project",
    "url": EcoPizzaCaseStudy // <-- React component, not a path string
  },
  {
    "image": Squared,
    "name": "The UX portfolio item name",
    "description": "This is description part",
    "role": "My role in that project",
    "url": SquaredCaseStudy // <-- React component, not a path string
  }
];
```

The imported components should be rendered by a `Route` component and the link should specify a target path string.

You'll need to explicitly render a route for the work projects you want to link to.

Example:

Update the work data to include the element you want to render on a specific route, and then set the URL path you want it to render on.

```
import EcoPizza from "../assets/project-icons/ecoPizza.webp";
import Squared from "../assets/project-icons/Squared.webp";
import { EcoPizzaCaseStudy, SquaredCaseStudy } from "./case-studies";

const WorkData = [
  {
    image: EcoPizza,
    name: "The UX portfolio item name",
    description: "This is description part",
    role: "My role in that project",
    element: <EcoPizzaCaseStudy />, // <-- route element
    path: "eco-pizza", // <-- route path
  },
  {
    image: Squared,
    name: "The UX portfolio item name",
    description: "This is description part",
    role: "My role in that project",
    element: <SquaredCaseStudy />,
    path: "squared",
  }
];

export default WorkData;
```

The `WorkCard` component will use the `path` to navigate relative from the `"/work"` path, i.e. to `"/work/eco-pizza"`.

```
const Work = () => {
  return (
    <div className="work">
      <section className="work-section">
        <div className="card">
          <h1 className="underline">My portfolio</h1>
          <p>Here are the case studies of my projects...</p>

          <div className="grid-layout grid-2">
            {
              WorkData.map((val) => {
                return (
                  <WorkCard
                    key={val.path}
                    path={val.path} // <-- path path through
                    image={val.image}
                    name={val.name}
                    description={val.description}
                    role={val.role}
                  />
                );
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const WorkCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <NavLink to={props.path} className="tile-card">
      <img src={props.image} alt={props.name} />
      <div className="details">
        <h2>{props.name}</h2>
        <p className="description" title={props.description}>
          {props.description}
        </p>
        <h4 className="role" title={props.role}>Role: {props.role}</h4>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
  );
}
```

Map the `WorkData` array to the project routes.

```
...
import WorkData from "./WorkData";
...

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <main>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/work">
              <Route index element={<Work />} />
              {/* "/work/eco-pizza", "/work/squared", etc... */}
              {WorkData.map(({ path, element }) => (
                <Route key={path} {...{ path, element }} />
              ))}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/under-construction" element={<UnderConstruction />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound />}/>
          </Routes>
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi again.. I tried this and the portfolio still kept pointing to the "/work" page. I found the answer by aarnas. But thank you so much for the effort put in to help me out. :)

Comment: @ProblemChild They used absolute root route paths where I suggested continuing to use relative route paths and to render the routes for them as ***nested*** routes. It's likely just a mixup somewhere with a path definition and/or where the target routes are located. Glad you have it resolved though. Cheers.